# Submitting iPhone App To App Store, Proper provision profile

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

We are in the process of submitting an iphone app to the app store.  We've tested it using an adhoc distribution provisioning profile, however I was wondering if I need to create a separate provisioning profile for the app store.

On the distribution tab in the provisioning area, it enables me to create a distribution provision profile for the app store.  Do I need to build the app with that in order to submit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the adhoc will not work, you need to rebuild / archive with the profile made for distribution app store

Answer (score 1):

Ad hoc would will not work. For me dealing the certificates and provisioning profiles is a very annoying experience.
This is what I needed to do to submit an app:

In Developer under iOS Provisioning Portal I needed to generate 4 certificates and download the WWDR intermediate certificate to be able to submit my app to the App Store:

1. Under Developer Certificate section ([link](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action)) generate a Developer Certificate. Also Make sure that you have the WWDR intermediate certificate installed, if in doubt download it from there.
2. Under Developer Certificate section ([link](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/distribute.action)) generate a Distribution Certificate (This is not that will show up in Xcode!)
3. Under Provisioning section ([link](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action)) generate a Development Provisioning profile certificate
4. Under Provisioning section ([link](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/viewDistributionProfiles.action))generate a Distribution Provisioning profile. THIS WILL SHOW UP IN XCODE AS A DISTRIBUTION CERTIFICATE!

After that I was able to select the iPhone distribution profile generated at 4. Also make sure that your target and project settings are the same.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Back in 2009, I did use my ad hoc provisioning profile to submit the app to the store:)

But looks like things have changed since then. I guess the answers say it will not work because the application validators detect this?