# A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload the IPA to Itunnes using altool, but I have an entitlement issue:

A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store

I have the same configuration in project and tarjet, with automatic manage signing enabled:

[image]

[image]

I have tried these, but no luck:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7254249/5677589

[Entitlements Do Not Match: Provisioning Profile Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335276/entitlements-do-not-match-provisioning-profile-issue)

Comment: Where do you get that error? Where in iTunes are you trying to upload an IPA?

Comment: Using the altool, is the command line tool of the application loader. Using the application loader, I get the same error as well.

Comment: Why you are using Altool. Xcode or Application loader is all ok. @

Froi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to make it `iOS Distribution` keep it similar to `iOS Developer`

**Check you have added correct account. Check bundle identifier same you have used in your provisioning profile.**

Try Archive. It would work!!

Comment: With all settings to iOS Developer, archive, be sure the account is logged in XCode, no luck. Weird.

Comment: Are you able to Archive it successfully?

Comment: Yes, I archive it correctly, but the problem is when I upload the IPA to the Itunnes. I got the error message detailed in the issue.

Comment: I will add you in a couple of hours, I'm out of office. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question after struggling to get Fastlane to upload my apps to TestFlight. I solved it by using the `appstore` [Match certificate and profile](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/) instead of the `development` one.

I think `development` should only be used locally.